# TRRS lavalier mic not recognized as input Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

I have a Macbook Pro 2015 (running MACOS 10.15.5 Cataline) and I recently bought a [lavalier microphone](https://www.amazon.ca/Professional-Microphone-Omnidirectional-Recording-Conference/dp/B01AG56HYQ) that worked for a while. Now, all of sudden my MBP won't recognize it as an input device. This microphone has a TRRS plug.

When I plug it in, the MIDI Sound menu switches the "build in output" icon from a speaker to a headphone.

The microphone **is** working, I can use it on my cell phone, I can record audio on a Windows computer.

I tried [this answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/60740/378499) but it didn't work.

Sometimes when I'm lucky my MBP does recognize it properly and recording works fine (and it used to work for a while).

Is there a way to force the plug to a certain pinout, instead of relying on the autodetection?

The microphone came with an adapter to a regular TRS 3.5 mm plug. Using the adapter makes no difference.

Thank you.

Comment: [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267161/external-mic-not-working-anymore-on-macbook-air) is three years old and doesn't have a answer. The best solution seems to be to ditch the Mac and get a decent computer, preferably running Linux.

Comment: The input jack doesn’t change pinouts.  More than likely it’s dirty causing a faulty connection.  That headphone jack is of poor quality (IMO).  Get a [high quality DAC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295628/119271)

Comment: That is not so simple, as the supply voltages aren't the same and the lavalier mic needs an adapter to work with 48 V phantom power.